# C++ Curl cannot get HTTPS content - SSL_read

Tags: c++, curl

I am writing a C++ application which uses Curl to send the requests.

- Curl version: 7.68.0
- C++: 20
- OS: Ubuntu 20.04
- OpenSSL: 1.1.1g

Response data is not returned when trying to connect to an external CGI over HTTPS (HTTP protocol works as exepcted).
The connection is established and the data is generated by the CGI (log result).

- Error: 'Failure when receiving data from the peer'
- Error code: 56
- Verbose error: "OpenSSL SSL_read: Connection closed abruptly, errno 0 (Fatal because this is a curl debug build)"

Code:

```
    // Output data
    std::string outputData;

    // Sets common parameters
    static constexpr const auto USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)";
    curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());
    curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, USER_AGENT);
    curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYSTATUS, false);
    curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_SSL_ENABLE_ALPN, false);
    curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_SSL_ENABLE_NPN, false);
    curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_SSL_FALSESTART, false);
    curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &outputData);
    curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, &onDataReceived);

    curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, url.c_str());
    //curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

onDataReceived:

```
size_t CurlRequest::onDataReceived
(
    char* ptr,
    size_t size,
    size_t nmemb,
    void* userdata
)
{
    static_cast<std::string*>(userdata)->append(ptr, size * nmemb);
    return size * nmemb;
}
```

#edit
Different URL over HTTPS also work as expected ...

Any idea?

Comment: Provide a [mcve], please!

Comment: What happens if you try use curl to the same url from command line with -v parameter?

Comment: @user2807083 Curl works fine when the "--insecure" flag is provided.

Comment: And you are passing the same parameters to the `curl` command, including the fake user agent?

Comment: No, full command: curl -X "POST" "<url>" -d "a=test" --insecure

Comment: @SamVarshavchik That was a problem ... without the user agent it works as expected, thanks!